# mandatory lookup column doesn't work

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, lookup-column, column

So I have a pretty basic scenario. Two lists (Projects and Clients). In the Projects list I have a mandatory lookup field that aims at the Clients Title column.

Now when I fill out the form for creating a new Projects list item and try to save it the form just reloads and nothing is created. There are no error messages what so ever.

It works when I set the column to not required, but well that's not a solution.

what am I missing?

Edit: Screenshots:

Lookup Column Configuration:
[image: Lookup column configuration]

Test form:
[image: Test form]

Comment: Can you please post the screenshot of the column settings?

Comment: @harshalgite I added the screenshots

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce this issue on my SharePoint 2013 environment. It showed correctly when I reopened the filled form.

Which version of SharePoint? 2013 or 2016 or Online? You can create another Projects list to check if this issue also occurs on the new list.

Comment: We are using SharePoint 2016. I tried it out on multiple lists on our test environment and our real system as I also thought that it just was a glitch or a misconfiguration on my side.

Comment: what is the build number of your farm?

Comment: It's 16.0.4618.1000